# Better way to split a string "a_b_c_d.1.2.3.4"

Tags: c#, string

what is the best ways to split sting "aaa_bx_cd_de.1000.20.3.40" to "aaa_bx_cd_de" and "1000.20.3.40" in C#.net application

```
mainstring="aaa_bx_cd_de.1000.20.3.40"
str1="aaa_bx_cd_de"
str2="1000.20.3.40"
```

Comment: What is the template? Are the alphabetic parts only single letters and the digits only one digit numbers? Because in this case just count the characters and split it base on that (no regex required!)

Comment: Anything that works is better than nothing.

Comment: Will you only ever have to split similar strings like that? If so, the standard `Split` method takes a count of how many substrings it returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an overload of `String.Split`[1] that takes as a second argument the number of substrings you want returned (essentially the number of splits plus 1).

```
string mainstring = "a_b_c_d.1.2.3.4";
string[] parts = string.Split(new [] {'.'}, 2);
// parts[0] will be "a_b_c_d"
// parts[1] will be "1.2.3.4"
```

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx